# OAuth2 Authorization Code with Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm developing an iOS app which uses Facebook Login. I have the Facebook iOS SDK set up and working, but the back-end developer of my client has concerns about the safety of Facebook's access tokens.

Using using the Facebook SDK, We want to get an authorization code from Facebook, not the access token, and get the access token on the server with App Key and App Secret. Is there any way of doing this?

Note: I am using this method to login (on FBSession):

```
openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question :

This can't be done with the current Facebook iOS SDK, but you can make a graph API call to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/client_code?access_token=...&client_id=...&client_secret=...&redirect_uri= ...
```

to exchange the access token with the code.

But this isn't secure at all, because you would have to ship the app with the App Secret.

Comment: True that mate. Even on Android, the Facebook Login SDK does not let you retrieve the auth code, only the access token. Because of this, if you disable the client oauth login for Facebook Login product in your app, you will not be able to log in with Facebook app from the device using the SDK.

Comment: However, the Account Kit SDK (to login with email / phone number) by facebook DOES NOT suffer from this. It lets you specify whether you want to retrieve token or code and accordingly returns only that.

Comment: Facebook forces the app to send the token to the server? Why doesn't it allow to get an Authorization code for the backend, so later the backend can get a token itself? This is a more secure way. I wonder why they force us to send the access token to backend.

Comment: 6 years later... and I'm doing this Graph request, but on the server-side. This is because I'm talking to a Ruby backend using the omniauth-facebook gem, and I need to simulate the full OAuth flow like it happens on the web :(